# Executing string queries from function

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql, dynamic-sql

I have a table called rezultz with 1 row only containing valid SQL queries like: CREATE TRIGGER ... I'm trying to execute them with this function called get_all_rezultz() but it doesn't seem to work,any ideas why?

```
       CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_all_rezultz() RETURNS SETOF rezultz AS
    $BODY$
  DECLARE
r rezultz%rowtype;
   BEGIN
FOR r IN
    SELECT * FROM rezultz 
LOOP
    -- can do some processing here
    RETURN QUERY EXECUTE r; -- return current row of SELECT
END LOOP;
RETURN;
 END
  $BODY$
 LANGUAGE plpgsql;

  SELECT * FROM get_all_rezultz();
```

Here is the error I get :

```
  NOTICE:  identifier "CREATE TRIGGER userman_if_modified_trg AFTER    INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON userman FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); " will be truncated to "CREATE TRIGGER userman_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE O"
   CONTEXT:  SQL statement "("CREATE TRIGGER userman_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON userman FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); ")"
```

PL/pgSQL function get_all_rezultz() line 10 at RETURN QUERY

```
    ERROR:  syntax error at or near ""CREATE TRIGGER userman_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON userman FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); ""
    LINE 1: ("CREATE TRIGGER userman_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPD...
     ^
  QUERY:  ("CREATE TRIGGER userman_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON userman FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); ")
      CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function get_all_rezultz() line 10 at RETURN QUERY
```

********** Error **********

```
   ERROR: syntax error at or near ""CREATE TRIGGER userman_if_modified_trg AFTER INSERT OR UPDATE OR DELETE ON userman          FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE audit.if_modified_func(); ""
    SQL state: 42601
     Context: PL/pgSQL function get_all_rezultz() line 10 at RETURN QUERY
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. What do you mean by "does not work"? Gives error? Does not deliver expected results?

Comment: Updated on where the error occurs

Comment: This is not going to work. What is the actual problem you are trying to solve with this? A function can't return multiple results and you can't run a DDL statement using `return query`. You should take a step back and explain us the underlying _problem_ you have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The variable `r` is a **record** containing multiple columns. It's not a scalar value (e.g. a string).

So you need to use the column name in the `execute` statement. Assuming the column in the table is called `sql_statement` you need to use:

```
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE r.sql_statement;
```

---

However, this will still not work because the select statement stored in that table will most definitely not return a results that is `SETOF rezultz` it returns a `SETOF mytable` if the query is `select * from mytable`.

You would need to specify `RETURNS SETOF record` but then you need to specify the column names and structure of the result when *calling* the function.

And even then this won't work because a function still only return a single result, not multiple results from multiple queries - which will happen if `rezultz`contains more then one row.

If your SQL statements aren't actually `SELECT` statements as you have claimed, you will need to use `EXECUTE` you can't use `RETURN QUERY` for a `CREATE TRIGGER` statement.

Comment: I get the following error - ERROR:  cannot open CREATE TRIGGER query as cursor

Comment: You can't run a `CREATE TRIGGER`  statement with `return query`. But you claimed that the table "*containing valid SQL queries like: SELECT*FROM mytable*" no mentioning of `create trigger` there.